# Document.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'traverse') Autodesk Viewer + React

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Since Sunday, February 18, I am experimenting in this project (react + Autodesk Viewer):
Proyect: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/viewer-react-sample
The following error:

> Document.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'traverse')
> at new Document (Document.js:54:18)
> at Function.onSuccess (Document.js:172:29)
> at onSuccessWrapped (Xhr.js:609:40)
> at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (Xhr.js:851:34)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feyd5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSl8L.png)

Before that date, I didn't have that, the problem didn't exist. I checked the updates and there was one on February 14 but I see no relation to the error. I tried different environments, browsers, computers, etc. Does anyone have any ideas?
Updates:
[https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7)

Install the proyect with dependencies ,but not run the models .

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to a recent change in the Viewer SDK. Before this change, it was possible to call `Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer` without specifying the `env` option, and the viewer would try to auto-detect the proper settings based on the URL of the website that's hosting it. After the change, the auto-detected settings might be different, so I'd recommend hard-coding the `env` property to be on the safe side. Please see this blog post for more details: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/getting-404-resource-not-found-error-viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Making some tests into `loadModel` function I faced this error too, the solution for me was add the `"urn:"`:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
   "urn:" + urn,
   onDocumentLoadSuccess,
   onDocumentLoadFailure
);
```